# Wordpress redirection on login

Tags: wordpress, redirect, authentication, preg-replace, preg-match-all

We have a bilingual Wordpress theme. The English version is at **mydomain.com** and the Czech version is in a virtual directory at **mydomain.com/cs/**

When a user logs in at **mydomain.com/login** they are redirected to **mydomain.com/dashboard** as specified in the code below (that is the page name). I need users logging in using **mydomain.com/cs/login** to be logged in to **mydomain.com/cs/dashboard**

The code in use for that function is here:

`<?php wp_login_form( apply_filters( 'atcf_shortcode_profile_login_args', array(
                        'redirect' => isset ( $edd_options[ 'profile_page' ] ) ? get_permalink( $edd_options[ 'profile_page' ] ) : home_url()
                    ) ) ); ?>`

**home_url** is what returns the full URL of the site. Any ideas how I can achieve a redirection by escaping the current directory (/login)?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` value to see if it starts with `/cs/` and then dynamically update the profile page value accordingly.

```
// The current URI (does not incude host/domain)
$uri = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
// The home URL
$redirect = home_url();

// $edd_options[ 'profile_page' ] must return the page ID for get_permalink to work
if ( isset( $edd_options[ 'profile_page' ] ) ) {

    // The profile URL. 
    $profile_page_id = $edd_options[ 'profile_page' ];
    $redirect = get_permalink( $profile_page_id );

    // Check if the URI starts with /cs/
    if ( strpos( $uri, '/cs/' ) == 0 ){
        // Explode into an array
        $url_array = explode( '/', $profile_page );

        // Insert /cs/ into array
        $url_array = array_slice($url_array, 0, 3, true) +
                 array("x"=>"cs") +
                 array_slice($url_array, 3, count($url_array)-3, true);

        // Implode back to a string
        $redirect = implode( '/', $url_array );
    }
}

// Set up params to send to login form
$args = apply_filters( 'atcf_shortcode_profile_login_args', array( 'redirect' => $redirect ) );
wp_login_form( $args );
```

Comment: Great stuff doublesharp! I replaced the current snippet of code with yours and while there were no obvious errors the page didn't go to the /cs/ page as it should have. I also realised that 'get_permalink' gets the permalink of the current page. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to add the '/cs/' to the the home url or the profile page? If it's the profile page you just need to modify the code to use its value instead of the home. [`get_permalink()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink) defaults to the current page, but will work for anything as long as you pass in the ID - not sure what the value of `$edd_options[ 'profile_page' ]` is however, if not the ID then that's the problem.

Comment: I updated the code to use the profile page, but the `$edd_options[ 'profile_page' ]` must be the page ID for it to work.